# Why doesn't MariaDB server recognise Server Audit settings in config file?

Tags: mariadb, configuration, audit, mariadb-10.4

I'm trying to implement the Server Audit plugin that is built-in with MariaDB 10.4.  I've added the settings to the `my.ini` config file, running on Windows 10.

```
[server]
...
#Audit Settings
server_audit_logging=ON
server_audit_output_type=FILE
server_audit_events=CONNECT, QUERY, TABLE
server_audit_excl_users=    #Default=blank
server_audit_file_path=D:/Databases/MariaDB/server_audit.log
server_audit_file_rotate_now=   #Default=0; choose 1 to create new log file, restart server, then reset to 0.
server_audit_file_rotate_size=  #Default=1000000
server_audit_file_rotations #Default=9 (range 0 to 999)
server_audit_incl_users=    #Default=blank
server_audit_query_log_limit=   #Default=1024
server_audit_syslog_facility=   #Default=LOG_USER; not relevant when using log to file.
server_audit_syslog_ident=  #Default=mysql-server_auditing; not relevant when using log to file.
server_audit_syslog_info=   #Default=blank; not relevant when using log to file.
server_audit_syslog_priority=   #Default=LOG_INFO; not relevant when using log to file.
```

But I can't start the server because of this error:

```
2020-04-17 19:26:20 0 [ERROR] D:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.4\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'server_audit_logging=ON'
```

I've tried putting the settings under `[mariadb]` and `[mysqld]` just in case that helped - it didn't.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you [installed the plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-audit-plugin-installation/)?

Comment: Isn’t it supposed to be included with version 10.4?  They added it as a default feature from 10.0.10 according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-audit-plugin-installation/#installing-the-plugin):

> Although the plugin's shared library is distributed with MariaDB by
>   default, the plugin is not actually installed by MariaDB by default.

So you need to install the plugin - either execute:

```
INSTALL SONAME 'server_audit';
```

Or put it in your option file:

```
[mariadb]
...
plugin_load_add = server_audit
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read past the "included by default".  I can't imagine what is the point of shipping it but not installing it.  So I've installed it using the first method `INSTALL SONAME 'server audit';`.  It still won't run, gives me the same unknown variable error plus this new error `[ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'SERVER_AUDIT' failed.`  The plugin appears to be working `SERVER_AUDIT | ACTIVE | AUDIT | server_audit.dll | GPL`

Comment: There is another new error `[ERROR] d:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.4\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value 'CONNECT, QUERY, TABLE' to 'server-audit-events'`  Also if I comment out all the server_audit parts of the .ini file the .err file shows `server_audit: MariaDB Audit Plugin version 1.4.8 STARTED.`